# Shift from phpmyadmin as Server to Google Cloud platform as server?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-platform

Currently I am using PhpMyAdmin as my server. Now I want to shift to Google cloud as my server.

I have few php files which are called as url from android app, these php file connects to mysql database and returns result back. Relative paths of images are stored in the database and these images are stored on server.

I am not able to figure out how I can perform same thing with Google cloud. I tried to upload same php file on google cloud and database to google cloud sql. But, I don't know how to access relative path images or individual php files, and I am lost as I am new to Google cloud.

Can someone please help? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using app engine or compute engine?

Comment: @AvinoamMeir I am using app engine.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use Google Cloud Storage:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/

Your site users can't upload their files directly to App Engine, so you can let them upload to Cloud Storage and then keep the metadata in your Cloud SQL.